# php split string on first occurrence of a letter

Tags: php, regex, string, split, explode

I have the following string

```
$string = "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68"
```

I would like to split it at the first letter found (the letter varies each time). I found a similar question that had the following example

```
$split = explode('-', 'orange-yellow-red',2);
echo $split[1]; //output yellow-red
```

But this is assuming you know what the letter is. Is there a way to specify any letter? I've used preg split before but that can't limit and also i'm not that good with regex.

If explode would work with regex then something like this may work, but this is just an example as this would not work.

```
$string = "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24";
$split = explode([A-Za-z], $string,2);
```

Comment: Wait.. What? How do you split on a letter that you don't know what it is?

Comment: @Rohit Something like split [A-Za-z], so in effect you're splitting on the first letter, not any other type of character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
$string = "18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09 DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68"

$stringArray = preg_split("/[a-zA-Z]/",$string,2);
```

the [a-zA-Z] tells it to find the first letter, and then it will split from there

`$stringArray` will hold the two resulting strings, note that it takes out the letter that it split on

You could though use [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) to get the two strings so that it will not strip out the first letter

```
preg_match("/([^a-zA-Z]+)(.*)/",$string,$Matches);
```

here the regular expression tells it to capture everything up to the first letter, and then capture everything after that

`$Matches[1]` would contain

```
18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09
```

and `$Matches[2]` would contain

```
DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68
```

`$Match[0]` holds the whole string that was matched.

Comment: `$stringArray = preg_split(/[a-zA-Z]/,$string,2);` is an error, isn't it?

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan typo, forgot the quotes

Comment: Thanks! `preg_match` seems to be the thing i needed!

Comment: You really shouldn't use preg_match - it's something of a code smell to use regular expressions to match an entire string outside of a validation context.

Comment: FrankieTheKneeMan's third solution is good as well and doesnt have the extra array element at the beginning

Answer (score 3):

Try [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php).

```
preg_split('/[a-z]/i', $string, 2);
```

I see you want to keep the letter - if you want it to go with the string before, use a lookbehind:

```
preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])/i', $string, 2);
```

if you want it to go with the string after, use a lookahead:

```
preg_split('/(?=[a-z])/i', $string, 2);
```

If you want it separated, up the number of splits and use both.

```
preg_split('/(?<=[a-z])|(?=[a-z])/i', $string, 3);
```

Here you go: [see it in action](http://ideone.com/5P8dak)

Comment: This works perfect if i change the 1 to a 2. The only problem is, is that it deletes the letter that it splits on? Is there a way of splitting it on the space before the letter?

Comment: Yeah, it does - what result were you actually seeking?

Comment: I was seeking to split the string at the first letter and keep both array items intact

Comment: But explode and split operations all delete the exploded/split part.  I meant:  do you want the letter on the string before it, or on the string after it, or as its own item?

Comment: I would like the split before it so it's like this eg `array([0]=>'18/05-01/06 01/06-06/07 06/07-22/08 22/08-14/09', [1]=>'DR Record + 2 21.47 20.24 27.15 20.24 BE Record + 2 24.05 22.68');`

Comment: I'm glad - you should consider marking either of these answers as "Accepted" so people after you know what worked.